# FQL - facebook image search by hashtag

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-fql

Is there any way to do a search using HASHTAG with GRAPH API?

so far have not found anything about it, I need to get some pictures with the same hashtag with them and generate a list of images with the same tag.

thank you

Sergio Mendes Oliveira

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a PCS partner you will not be able to access the API available for searching hashtags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights/

Access to this API is not available and cannot be applied to currently.